# RegEx exact repetition is not working

Tags: regex

I am a noob in RegEx and I am trying to write a RegEx pattern that has a minimum of 6 and maximum of 9 total characters, where the first 3 characters are letters (case-insensitive, alpha only) and the rest are digits.

I have the following pattern: `^\w{3}\d{3,6}$`

But for some reason, that pattern returns true when I enter the following: `aa12345` or `Ap4587` and so on. I need that the first 3 characters are only letters (exact).

I hope someone will be able to help me on this.

Thanks!!!

Comment: `\w` is for alphanumeric characters and `_`

Answer (score 5):

`\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. You should change the regex to:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{3,6}$
```

Comment: Well... `\w` is not *exactly* equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. It depends on the engine. In .NET, for example, `\w` is usually equivalent to `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\p{Lm}]`. If you truly wanted to match `\w` minus the digits and punctuation, I believe you'd use `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Lm}]`

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 Well, yes. I wasn't considering the unicode characters there.

Answer (score 2):

Use `[a-zA-Z]` for only alphabets. I prefer using `[0-9]` even it's same as `\d` for consistency

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3,6}$/
```

`\w` matches `a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _` and should only be used for alphanumeric character

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow a broader range of unicode values, I'd recommend:

```
[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Lm}]{3}
```

This will allow lowercase, uppercase, title, "other" and modifiers as your first three characters.

For example, `[a-zA-Z]{3}` would exclude the word "Résumé" because of the special characters. The pattern above would allow it.

I recommend you check out the documentation for regular expression character classes:

**[Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)**

The MSDN documentation is also very good and most of it is compatible with standard regex libraries:

**[Character Classes in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{3,6}$
```

as `\w` matches `a-z, A-Z, 0-9`